# i try to implement merge sort algorythm using python but the code doesn't work well

Tags: python, sorting

here merge function:

```
def __merge__(arr, middle):

    L = arr[:middle]
    R = arr[middle:]

    L.append(math.inf)
    R.append(math.inf)

    i = 0
    j = 0
    for k in range(0, len(arr)):

        if(L[i] <= R[j]):
            arr[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            arr[k] = R[j]
            j += 1

    return arr
```

and here mergesort function that call intself recursively:

```
def __mergeSort__(listOfNumber):

if(len(listOfNumber) <= 1):
    return listOfNumber

middle = int( len(listOfNumber) / 2 )

print('merge lit: ', listOfNumber[:middle])
__mergeSort__(listOfNumber[:middle])
print('merge lit: ', listOfNumber[middle:])
__mergeSort__(listOfNumber[middle:])
print(__merge__(listOfNumber, middle))
return __merge__(listOfNumber, middle)
```

when I give array like[6,5,4,3,2,1] as input i receve this: [3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4]

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: write down the expected output for each step on a paper, and debug your code, I am sure you can find what is wrong if you do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the result of running `merge_sort` on both halves:

```py
    def merge_sort(lst):

        if len(lst) <= 1:
            return lst

        middle = len(lst) // 2 
        left = merge_sort(lst[:middle])
        right = merge_sort(lst[middle:])
        return merge(left, right)
```

You will need to modify the `merge` function so that it accepts two lists as arguments.